# Returning values from functions in lua modules

Tags: module, lua

Is it possible to return the value from an individual function within a module?
The examples of functions within modules that do something simple like:

```
function add(x,y)
    print(x+y)
end
```

But I'd like to return the value, not just print it.

i've tried several things [the most obvious]:

```
function module.add(x,y)
    return x+y;
end
```

what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You are showing the correct way to do this. What problem did you run into? You need to include the minimal script that reproduces the issue along with the expected results.

Comment: @NotMyName google is your friend:) [See](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_modules.htm)

Comment: csaar:  As much as I love passive aggressive commenting... I have read this linked article, and even included that example in the question.  It is printing the answer - not returning with the capability to work with the do anything with it.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko thanks; i must have had a typo previously.  i was writing up a sample to explain, and it's working as i thought it should.